# Setting Up HighScore in Swift and Sprite Kit using NSuserdefaults

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am building a swift game and a need to set up a highscore , i have been trying to figure out how to do it for a while. So please can you tell me how to search this library to see if there is a already saved high score and then compare it to the user's score. I have tried coming out with this but it won't work. Please Help and be as clear as possible. Giving me example code would be extremely appreciated.

```
    if let highscore: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.valueForKey("highscore") { 
      var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highScore") as Int
        if ( savedScore < Score) { 
            var highscore = Score
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey:"highscore")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() }
    }
    else { 
        var highscore = Score
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey:"highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
   }
```

Comment: Why not iCloud? Suppose user will uninstall app or will run on other device ...

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't work`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a new iOS project in Xcode by using the *Single View Application* template. Then, replace the content of `ViewController.swift` with the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var generator = [6, 12, 8].generate()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .System)
        button.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "newScore", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        // Auto layout code using anchors (requires iOS9+)
        let horizontalConstraint = button.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = button.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerYAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
        
        // Print NSUserDefaults's highscore value when app is launched
        print("highscore:", NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore"))
    }
    
    func newScore() {
        guard let score = generator.next() else { return }
        print("current score:", score)

        //Check if score is higher than NSUserDefaults stored value and change NSUserDefaults stored value if it's true
        if score > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
        
        print("highscore:", NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore"))
    }
    
}
```

---

Build and run the project on your iPhone or on the simulator. The Xcode console will print 0, which is the current value for `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")`.

Now, click on the button. This will set the value of `score` to `6` and, because `6 > 0`, `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` will get this new value.

Click once again on the button. This will set the value of `score` to `12`. You will immediately see in the console that `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` gets this new value.

Now, if you change the value of `score` to `8` by clicking on the button, you will see that `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` still has a value of `12` because `8 < 12`.

If you rebuild your project and relaunch it, you will see that `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` is persistent (its value is still 12 and has not been reset). Therefore, `NSUserDefaults` can be a perfect tool in order to store your players highest scores.

---

#### Extra tip

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` always return an `Int` (if you haven't set it by yourself, it will return `0`, not `nil`). Thus, you dont need to / can't use optional binding with it. If you really want to deal with an optional value return, you will prefer `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore") as? Int`.

Comment: That is exactly what i needed.I can see now how this operates. Thank  you very much @POB

Answer (score 1):

```
var defaults=NSUserDefaults()
var highscore=defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

if(Score>highscore)
{
    defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "highscore")
}
var highscoreshow=defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

lblHighScore.text="\(highscoreshow)"
println("hhScore reported: \(lblHighScore.text)")
lblPlayScore.text="\(Score)"
println("play reported: \(lblPlayScore.text)")
```