# NSUserDefaults recall in other scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scene

I followed this advice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587299/setting-up-highscore-in-swift-and-sprite-kit-using-nsuserdefaults). I now have

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene {

var score = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

   if score > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
   }

   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

   }
}
```

I have more code that adds 1 to the score when a certain argument is met. But my question is how I can recall the ("highscore") key in another scene. Another scene is called when the game is over and it's called GameOverScene.

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene {

var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    gameOverLabel.text = //here I want the highScore to be displayed
    gameOverLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    gameOverLabel.fontSize = 100
    gameOverLabel.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX, frame.midY)
    self.addChild(gameOverLabel)

   }
}
```

What do I have to do to add the highscore onto my scene

Comment: Just call `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` ?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

does nothing (both times). You can **retrieve** values from user defaults by assigning them to a variable, e.g. to display them

```
let score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
label.text = "\(score)"
```

And you can **set** it as you are doing in the first line of your `if` closure.

Comment: But can I retrieve them in another scene. So for example I have in my GameScene `let score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` but I want to display it in my GameOverScene. That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code does not show them because **you are not assigning the read value to a variable**.